# Not diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have the following matrix of dimension $n\times n$:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
        a_{1} & 1 & \\
         & a_1 & 1 & \\
        & & \ddots & 1\\
        & && a_{1} \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

Where $a_1 \in \mathbb{C}$. I need to show that $A$ is not diagonalizable. And here is what I have done:

$\textbf{det }(A-I\lambda) = (a_1-\lambda)^n$

Now, what this means is that there is only one eigenvalue for this matrix. This, being $\lambda = a_1$. Therefore, there is only one eigenspace associated, meaning that the matrix cannot be further decomposed. Since the matrix cannot be further decomposed, it cannot be diagonalized.

Is this enough to prove that $A$ is not diagonalizable?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: $A$ is already a diagonal matrix. How can it not be diagonalisable?

Comment: I was told it should be thought of as a Jordan Block

Comment: Not sure what you were told, but every nonzero vector is an eigenvector of your $A$. The eigenspace is not one-dimensional.

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing 1's above the $a_1$ diagonals? Then it is not diagonalizable but is in Jordan normal form. Otherwise you were told wrong. Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $n>1,A$ is not diagonal. There is exactly one eigenvalue, $a_1,$ which has algebraic multiplicity $n.$ A basis for the corresponding eigenspace is the vector with 1 as the first entry and all other entries 0. Thus the dimension of the eigenspace is 1. Since $1 \ne n$ the matrix $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can show it directly that $A$ is not diagonazible. If $A$ is diagonazible then you can find an invertible matrix $T$ s.t. $T^{-1}AT=a_1I$ where $a_1$ is the only eigenvalue as you said. So, 
$$AT=T(a_1I)=a_1T\Rightarrow A=a_1TT^{-1}=a_1I$$
but clearly that $A\neq a_1I$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial factors out completely with $m(\lambda) = 1$ where $m(\lambda)$ denote the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue,

To conclude that $A$ is not diagonalizable we just have to note that the minimal polynomial $m_{A}(t)$ of $A$ is $m_{A}(t) = (1-t)^{n}$

(Same as the characteristic polynomial)

Comment: Do you really believe that you need to mention eigenvectors and endomorphisms in order to prove that a **diagonal** matrix is diagonalizable?